# Alinhamentos css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Meu caso é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero deixar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
    <div id="problema">

    <div id="verificar" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;">

    <h1  style=" clear: both;position: relative; display: table; " >Log<sub>4</sub> <sup>64</sup> = 
    <input style=" display: table;" type="text" id="valor_total" /></h1>

    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 // Não sei o css que deverei usar :D
 // já tentei vários :/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deixo duas opções, ambas usando o `display: inline;`.
A diferença é que o `inline` não faz quebra de linha. O `display: block;` insere a quebra de linha que você não quer.

#### #1

Tirar o `<input>` de dentro do `<h1></h1>` e colocar o header com `display: inline;`. Aí nem precisa de `style=" display: table;"` no `<input>`.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLN2Z/2/

#### #2

Colocar `style=" display: inline;"` no `<input>`.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLN2Z/1/

---

E se quiser ajudtar a posição vertical do `<input>` pode usar assim:

```
input {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLN2Z/3/

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

**SUGESTAO**

Pra o seu caso você poderia simplesmente usar as tags **sup** e **sub**, a nao ser que queiras forçosamente passar pelo **css**.

Aqui esta um **Exemplo** :

```html
<div style="font-size: 40px;">
    <span>Log</span><sub>4</sub><sup>64</sup> = 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="verificar">
    <h1  style=" clear: both;position: relative; display: table; " >Log<sub>4</sub> <sup>64</sup> =     
</div>
<div id="campo">
    <input style=" display: table;" type="text" id="valor_total" /></h1>
</div>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    #verificar{
        width: 125px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
    #campo{
        float: left;
        margin-top: 32px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Oi Rafael, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. É legal explicar *porque* seu código resolve o problema. Confira o guia [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Ola para a correção desse problema nos temos a opção de  esta ultilizando o display: inline;
o inline não faz quebra de linha. O display: block; insere a quebra de linha que você não quer faça o retiramento do   de dentro do

e colocar o header com display: inline;. Aí nem precisa de style=" display: table;" no .